# Matrix (list) in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I want to create a matrix ROW x COLS based on another matrix original size ROW x COLS.

```
ROWS = len(mat)
COLS = len(mat[0])
    
res = [[0 for i in range(ROWS)] for i in range(COLS)]
```

The above code doesn't work for the following edge case:

```
mat = [[3],[4],[5],[5],[3]]
```

My desired output is:

```
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

However, what I get is:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

How can I adapt my code to work with any case? ( I do not want to use numpy or any other libraries)

Comment: res = [[0 for i in range(COLS)] for i in range(ROWS)] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> [[0 for i in range(len(mat[0]))] for j in range(len(mat))]
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

Also better to use different loop variables instead of `i` for both:

Answer (score 2):

Swap the ROWS and COLS like so:

```
res = [[0 for i in range(COLS)] for i in range(ROWS)]
```